# Fetch Nacos Config in Unit Test in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, nacos

I'm trying to write a xUnit test for `HomeController`, and some important configuration information is put into `Nacos`.

**The problem now is that I can't get the configuration information in nacos.**

Here is my test class for `HomeController`:

```
using Xunit;

namespace ApiTestProject

    public class HomeControllerTest
    {

        // mock register services.  in this method, I can not access the nacos config strings
        private void Init()
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

            // add appsettings.json and nacos
            builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(cbuilder =>
            {
                cbuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            });
            var nacosconfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("NacosConfig");
            builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                // add nacos
                builder.AddNacosV2Configuration(nacosconfig);
            });



            // Now I should have been able to get the config info in builder.Configuration
            // try to get the "DbConn" in nacos, but connstr is null
            string connstr = builder.Configuration["DbConn"];

            // other register logic... 
        }
    }
```

And this is the `appsettings.Test.json` file:

```
{
  "NacosConfig": {
    "Listeners": [
      {
        "Optional": false,
        "DataId": "global.dbconn",
        "Group": "DEFAULT_GROUP"
      }
    ],
    "Namespace": "my-dev",
    "ServerAddresses": [
      "http://mynacos.url.address/"
    ],
    "UserName": "dotnetcore",
    "Password": "123456",
  }
}
```

**Update:** I've checked in detail to make sure there aren't any spelling mistakes, case sensitivity issues. And the code in `Init()` function works well in the `Program.cs` file in the tested API project, but in this xUnit project, it's not working at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making sure that the `appsettings.Test.json` file is included in the output directory when you build?

Comment: Oooops!!! You solved my problem. This is exactly what I missed. 
if anyone has encountered a similar issue, please note: set the  ‘copy to output directory‘ to ‘always true‘ for ‘appsettings.json’ file.

Comment: Happy to hear! Please mark my answer as the solution then :-D